# Mass update CampaignMember records using tuple?

Tags: apex, campaign

I have a number of CampaignMember records containing the CampaignId and the Lead/Contact ID.

Is there a way to upsert these records without having to query CampaignMember for their ID's first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I've found to do this is by creating my own external key which is a composite of the LeadId+CampaignId.

In all subsequent updates/inserts, I would do an upsert using my external key.